# Is there a way to change Site and all Subsite logo URL with a certain value to another?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to change the logo URL specified in

```
Site Settings->Look And Feel->Title, description, and Icon
```

For a site and all sub-sites that have a specific logo URL while avoiding those that have a different value? Maybe a Powershell script?

We have a large number of sites with a logo we'd like to change, but some unique ones that we don't want to touch.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a bit of javascript and jquery to your branding, to test for a particular url and then switch the logo with jquery.

Comment: Hm... interesting... Would that be using SPServices?

Comment: No need. What i did was add a Literalcontrol into my branding topnavigation.ascx control which appears on everypage. Then if(spcontext.current.web.url.contains('newyork')) { literalcontrol.text="$(document).ready(Function() {$('#ctl100_onetidheadbnne2').attr('src','/layouts/images/usa.png');});"
#ctl100 is the id to the image for the site.

Works perfectly, can add other tests